# Apollo Client cache and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

everyone!

I use Next.js and `getStaticProps` function in order to fetch data on server side. And it fetches data well but with one exception.

I receive error `Can't find field '<field>' on ROOT_QUERY object` after executing function `client.readQuery({ query: QUERY })`.

And when I looked in `client.cache.data.data` on client side I noticed that field that I tried to fetch from cache and which was fatched on server side is not in `ROOT_QUERY` but near it(red color).

And in ROOT_QUERY I can see only field which was fetched on client side(green color). [image]

But on server side there are all fields in `ROOT_QUERY`[image].

Of course I can pass fetched data via props and use them but I would like to use cache instead.

If anyone faced with this I would like to receive an advice how to handle this.
Thanks.

[Here is my apollo-client configuration.](https://github.com/andreyohiienko/active-rest/blob/master/client/apollo/index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed `initialApolloState` in _app.tsx.

[image]

And in `getStaticProps()`

[image]